# What does a slash over a line in a circuit diagram mean?

Tags: diagram, symbol

In the following diagram (from the book by William Stallings, *Computer Organization and Architecture*), what does the slash `/` over the lines mean?

For example, there is a `/` through the line labeled `s + w` on the top.  Why is it there, and what does it mean?

[image: Direct-Mapping Cache Organization]

Comment: The slash indicates that it is a bus. The letters near the slash are numerical variables representing the number of individual lines in the bus.

Comment: Note that this isn't a circuit diagram per se, but rather an abstraction of an algorithm whose behavior is equivalent to said circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents a bus or a set of parallel lines, and the value next to it is the number of individual lines.

Comment: Thanks! Is this a common convention for circuit diagrams (or abstractions of circuit diagrams, as pointed out by Ignacio), or is it specific to this book?

Comment: @AttributedTensorField: It's very common.

Comment: But not on circuit schematics but on block diagrams.

Comment: letter is not a qty here

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What is it then? Do you mean it is a number of bits rather than physical lines?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Even with "s-r" and "s+w"?

Comment: my answer explains that it is not a value but a bus name  , they are merged and separated for different reasons of segmenting cache hits

Comment: I think it can be read dually here. `s-r` might mean the lines of `s` with the lines of `r` excluded, or just "the number of `s` bits minus the number of `r` bits". Both interpretations seem correct to me.

Comment: It is also not obvious what exactly the circle with an X in it means, what does it mean?

Comment: @AttributedTensorField: Multiplication, unless the text suggests otherwise.

Comment: From the logic in the diagram, wouldn't it be better to use AND than multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

The SRWT busses are simplified to a single line with each designated by a single letter for Shift, Register, Word & Tag.

Memory requests and responses   include a tag that has a shift value indicating the misalignment between the first byte of required packet data and the first byte of a line of data in memory.

- t = Tag = Shift - Register address
- r = Register address
- w = word = data in parallel bytes

The letters do not define numbers of lines in each bus *in this case*, although in most block diagrams it does.